# Elasticsearch - Terms Aggregation nested field

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have following problem. I have a nested field ("list") with 2 properties (fieldB & fieldC).
This is how a document looks like:

```
"fieldA: "1",
"list": [
  {"fieldB": "ABC",
  "fieldC": "DEF"},
  {"fieldB": "ABC",
  "fieldC": "GHI"},
  {"fieldB": "UVW",
  "fieldC": "XYZ"},...]
                        },
```

I want to get a distinct list of all possible fieldC values for "ABC" (fieldB) over all documents. So far I've tried this in Java (Java REST Client):

```
 SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("abc*");
 QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
             .must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("aList", 
             QueryBuilders.matchQuery("list.fieldB.keyword", "ABC"), ScoreMode.None));
 SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
 sourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder)
              .aggregation(AggregationBuilders.nested("listAgg","list")
              .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("fieldBAgg")
              .field("list.fieldB.keyword")));

    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
        searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Nested list = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("listAgg");
    Terms fieldBs = list.getAggregations().get("fieldBAgg");
```

With that query I get all documents which include "ABC" in fieldB and I get **all** fieldC values. But I just want the fieldC values where fieldB is "ABC".

So in that example I get DEF, GHI and XYZ. But i just want DEF and GHI. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nested` constraint in the query part will only select all documents that do have a nested field satisfying the constraint. You also need to add that same constraint in the aggregation part, otherwise you're going to aggregate all nested fields of all the selected documents, which is what you're seeing. Proceed like this instead:

```
// 1. terms aggregation on the desired nested field
nestedField = AggregationBuilders.terms("fieldBAgg").field("list.fieldC.keyword");

// 2. filter aggregation on the desired nested field value
onlyBQuery = QueryBuilders.termQuery("list.fieldB.keyword", "ABC");
onlyBFilter = AggregationBuilders.filter("onlyFieldB", onlyBQuery).subAggregation(nestedField);

// 3. parent nested aggregation
nested = AggregationBuilders.nested("listAgg", "list").subAggregation(onlyBFilter);

// 4. main query/aggregation
sourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder).aggregation(nested);
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my code, I was aggregating fieldB instead of fieldC. Please try it again